# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in flash.pug while rendering the view in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash) in my express app:

```
const express = require("express")
const flash = require("flash")
const session = require("express-session")
const path = require("path")
const app = express()

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "pug")
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public"))) //public folder!
app.use(session({
    key: 'user_sid',
    secret: 'sessionSecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("index").flash('info', 'Test Flash Message!')
})

const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 8080
const host = process.env.APP_HOST || "localhost"

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + host + ":" + port)
})
```

My `index` file looks like the following:

```
for message in flash
  a.alert(class='alert-' + message.type)
    p= message.message#
```

However, I get the following error when I call my index file:

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/src/views/partials/flash.pug:1
  > 1| for message in flash
    2|   a.alert(class='alert-' + message.type)
    3|     p= message.message

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:53:31)
    at eval (eval at wrap (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:76:4)
    at template (eval at wrap (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:84:162)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:428:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:418:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:465:11)
    at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: i think you haven't initalized flash as shown in readme doc.

Comment: @Panther Thank you for your answer. I was also thinking that this `  res.render("index").flash('info', 'Test Flash Message!')` does not might be viable syntax. Any way to write it better?

Comment: I don't know know by heart what `res.render` returns. The problem however is that `res.render("index")` (and therefore the rendering)  is then executed before `.flash('info', 'Test Flash Message!')` code is executed, so at the time you do the rendering not flash message is there. Reorder your code to `res.flash('info', 'Test Flash Message!'); res.render("index");` and test if it works then.

Comment: And like @Panther said, the `app.use(require('flash')());` does not appear in the the code. You should add the line before you use `res.flash`.